# MVC - navigate to home on application start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, routes

i added the following routes in my routetable.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                             
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",                      
            new { action = "Index", id = "" } 
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Root",    
            "",        
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",                                                 
            "Index",                                         
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
        );
```

and i can navigate to the home page (manually).  But the application will not navigate on app start.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: my app starts: http://domain/vdir1/vdir2/home.aspx/index

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, select any file that is not .aspx when you start debugging. If you start while you have home.aspx open, it will try to load that page directly, although wiht the wrong url. The result is that "domain/vdir1/vdir2/home" becomes controller in your first route, and the action "Index" is added, as you provide that as a default value.

Answer (score 1):

this code block would work just changed router name

```
routes.MapRoute(
        ".netx",
        "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
        new
        {
            action = "Index",
            id = ""
        });


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

and please be sure on the application start page

[image: and please be sure on the application start page]